# Controller Testing For SPRING-MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, testing, spring-mvc, junit

I am getting error in my controller Saying Null Pointer Exception while When I don't perform the testing. Everything works fine.

```
Controller :
@RequestMapping(value = "/studentinsection/{sectionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView studentInSectionForm(@ModelAttribute("studentInSectionFormData") StudentInSectionForm studentInSectionFormData,
                                             @PathVariable Integer sectionId,
                                             ModelMap model) {
        ArrayList<StudentInSections> studentInSectionList = (ArrayList<StudentInSections>)
                studentInSectionsService.retrieveAllStudentInSections(sectionId, 1);

        StudentSection studentSection = studentSectionService.retrieveStudentSection(sectionId);

        logger.info("section Name is:" + studentSection.getSectionName());

        ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (StudentInSections studentInSections : studentInSectionList) {
            String studentName =
                    (userService.retrieveUserName(studentInSections.getStudentId(), 1));
            User users = userService.retrieveUser(studentName);
            userList.add(users);
        }


        logger.info("sectionId is " + sectionId);

        ArrayList<User> allStudents = (ArrayList<User>)
                userService.retrieveAllStudents();

        studentInSectionFormData.setStudentInSectionList(studentInSectionList);
        model.addAttribute("studentList", allStudents);
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
        model.addAttribute("studentSectionName", studentSection.getSectionName());
        model.addAttribute("studentSectionId", studentSection.getSectionId());
        return new ModelAndView("studentinsection", "studentInSectionFormData", studentInSectionFormData);
    }


Testing is as follow:

    @Test
    public void testStudentInSectionForm() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/studentinsection/1"))
                .andExpect(status().isFound())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("studentinsection"));
    }
```

this is passing everything into the controller fine even sectionId is getting printed 1 in logger than also studentin sectionList returns nullMointerException.  help me to resolve my problem.. Thanx

Comment: I have set everything fine. All entity works. A simple testing having no values in controller is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It slooks like the context is not being loaded correctly. What is the exception stacktrace.

You can also view the request if you do :

```
  mockMvc.perform(get("/studentinsection/1"))
   .andExpect(status().isFound())
   .andDo(print())
```

Comment: Context is loaded correctly. It works for other sontroller and i tried this but no change in logger output.

Comment: You have a different a context for testing ? show the error message

Comment: FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 1 ms
INFO : co.softwarehouse.olt.web.controller.StudentInSectionController - section Id is:1
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.223 sec <<< FAILURE!
testStudentInSectionForm(controller.StudentInSectionControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.222 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: you have missed the interesting bit of the error ... update yr question with more stack trace. How are you setting cotnext for the test ?

Comment: An Xml File is in contextConfiguration. It is working all fine.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at co.softwarehouse.olt.web.controller.StudentInSectionController.studentInSectionForm(StudentInSectionController.java:55)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)